# Windows display on Insignia 32" TV/Monitor

Tags: display

HP Slimline connected to Insignia 32" TV. I am satisfied with the resolution at 1920 X 1080, however the window image is larger than what the TV/Monitor can display. The left margin displays only half the icons of the Classic Shell menu and the bottom also shows only part of the icons. Same holds true with the other corners.[Chopped off image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IdE7k.jpg)

When selecting the next display option at 1680 X 1050, the whole window shows up properly at lower resolution, but then there are two large black areas on the left and the right. There seems to be a trade off: take the better resolution with the cut out borders or take the lower resolution with those awful black areas.

Is it possible to accommodate an intermediate option, or is that governed by the TV/Monitor hardware and therefore fixed.

Thanks

Comment: The way to fix this is dependent on the specific model of Insignia 32" TV, can you edit your question to include the model number from the back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a NS-32D420NA16 [go in to the menu, go in to picture, then go in to Advanced settings](http://www.insigniaproducts.com/cms/documents/manuals/televisions/NS-32D420NA16/Default.htm#NS-32D420NA16/Adjusting-the-TV-picture.htm%3FTocPath%3DAdjusting%2520the%2520picture%7C_____1). From there set `Overscan` to `Off`, that should fix the problem you are having.

If you are using a different model the fix may be similar but the menus may look different than the manual I linked to.

You also may want to check that the `Aspect Ratio` is set to `Normal` and not `Zoom`.

Comment: One question, one answer and just the correct answer. Lucky day. I had this problem for some time until I finally decided to find a solution. Thank you very much, Scott.